# Динамический select vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Есть компонент в котором создаются два поля select(country, city) по клику. Поля зависимые, при выборе страны изменяются значения во втором селекте (города). Проблема заключается в том, что когда мы изменяем один select(страна) изменяются все другие select-ы (города).

```
 <template>

<b-container class="bv-example-row">

  <b-row v-for="(station, counter) in stations" v-bind:key="counter">
    <b-col cols="6">
      <label>Страна</label>
      <select class='form-control' name="country_dest_id" v-model='station.country' @change='getStates($event)'>
        <option value='0' >Select Country</option>
        <option v-for='data in countries' :value='data.id'>{{ data.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </b-col>

    <b-col cols="6">
      <label >Город</label>
      <select class='form-control' v-model='station.state'>
        <option value='0' >Select State</option>
        <option v-for='data in states' :value='data.id'>{{ data.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </b-col>

   

    <b-col cols="1">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" @click="deleteStation(counter)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Удалить</button>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>

  <b-row class="justify-content-md-center">
    <b-col cols="3" md="3">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" @click="addStation">Добавить</button>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
</template>
```

```
<script>

export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted.')
  },

  data(){
    return {
      stations:[
        {
          country: '',
          state:'',
        }
      ],
      countries: [],
      states:[]
    }
  },

  methods:{
    addStation(){
      this.stations.push({
        country:'',
        state: ''
      })
    },

    deleteStation(counter){
      this.stations.splice(counter,1);
    },

    getCountries: function(){
      axios.get('/getCountries')
          .then(function (response) {
            this.countries = response.data;
          }.bind(this));
    },


    getStates: function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      axios.get('/getStates',{
        params: {
          country_id: event.target.value
        }
      }).then(function(response){
        this.states = response.data;
      }.bind(this));

    }

  },

  created: function(){
    this.getCountries()
  }


}
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в одинаковых v-model, которые, когда создаете новый селект, ссылаються на одну и туже переменую, как вариант можно сделать масив обьектов из переменных, чтоб динамически по индексу добавлять туда и связывать с select через v-model тогда в каждом select будет своя переменная куда вносить свое значение